# What is the meaning of gradient & progression rate?

Tags: biostatistics, gradient

**Event Rates Over Time for a 60-Year-Old Patient With Baseline Peak Aortic Valve (AV) Gradient of 25 mm Hg and Progression Rate of Aortic Stenosis of 5 mm Hg/Yr**

I have following questions:
Q1. Does Gradient mean slope?

Q2. Does this progression rate mean arithmetic progression?

Q3. Can I conclude that, if 60 year old has AV gradient of 25 mm Hg then in the next year (or when he reaches 61) his AV gradient will rise to 30 mm Hg (i.e. 25 + 5). Similarly when he turns 62, his AV gradient will rise to 35 mm Hg?

Q4. Can I say the same thing (as in Q3.) for other ages, for example 65 year?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a medical question. The gradient here refers to the pressure gradient across the valve. It's really just the pressure on the value (measured in millimeters of mercury) [See here for example](http://www.clevelandclinicmeded.com/medicalpubs/diseasemanagement/cardiology/aortic-valve-disease/). In general, as you get progressively worse aortic stenosis the pressure gradient goes up. In this case it seems to be going up 5mm Hg/Yr so yes every year it tends to go up 5mm Hg. You can extrapolate however you want but it's likely these models become less accurate the further you progress in time.